# Process Javascript date string in Apex

Tags: visualforce, javascript, date

Im sending from Javascript Remoting datetime in this format : "2017-04-04T00:00:00". Whats the safest and best method to parse this kind of date format in Apex to `Date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's so many different routes you could take this, safest and best method is debatable when it comes to parsing dates, but you could do something as easy as

```
Date dt = Date.valueOf('2017-04-04T00:00:00'); //2017-04-04 00:00:00
System.debug('dt' + dt);
```

Check out [Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm).